# jquery custom plugin in joomla is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I'm trying to add a custom jquery plugin. But I get the error jQuery(...).termifier is not a function.... I'm pretty sure that there are no mistakes in code

For just test I have tried to copy the code from learn.jquery.com

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.greenify = function() {
        this.css("color", "green");
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

and then

```
jQuery('..').greenify();
```

which returns me error  jQuery('..').greenify is not a function

What is going on??? Does anyone know the reason of that?

EDIT

the more code. This greenify thing was just to show that it is not working on the standard example....

the actual plugin... It is placed currently just in the same file where later it is called on ellements, so no problem with file not found..

```
 (function($) {
  $.fn.termifier = function(options) {
   options = $.extend({
      lookupResource: 'getTerm',
     flyoutClass: 'lookerUpperFlyout'
  },options||{});

   this.attr('title','Click me for my definition!');

   return this.click(function(event){
    $.ajax({
       url: options.lookupResource,
       type: 'get',
       data: {term: this.innerHTML},
       dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
      $('<div></div>')
        .css({
          position: 'absolute',
          left: event.pageX,
          top: event.pageY,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          display: 'none'
        })
        .html(data)
        .addClass(options.flyoutClass)
        .click(function(){
          $(this).fadeOut(1500,function(){$(this).remove();});
         })
        .appendTo('body')
        .fadeIn();
      }

    });
    return false;
  });
 };
  }(jQuery));


 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 ...
 jQuery('abbr').termifier({
    lookupResource: 'some.php'
  });

 });
```

I'm pretty clueless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, ensure you're importing jQuery using **Joomla's API**, like so:

```
<?php
   JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
?>
```

This will ensure only 1 instance of jQuery is imported, and in noConflict mode too.

Once done, you should use the `jQuery` global scope and `$` as an alias (optional):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.fn.greenify = function() {
        this.css("color", "green");
        return this;
    };
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! Your answer has worked out! I have put the plugin inside the document ready function and it works.... But I still don't really understand why. That should normally work also if it is put outside the dom ready?? And in case that I want to load it separately in another file???

Comment: Joomla use Mootools, therefore the `$` which we normally use will sometimes cause conflicts between jQuery scripts and Mootools. This is why we use `jQuery` as the global scope and `$` only as an alias. It won't work outside DOM Ready because it's a jQuery plugin

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, That is why we use noConflict() function (which is also standard the part of jdoc:include type="head".) After using that function you can not use $ to call jQuery anyway, you ne to adress it as jQuery. That is why we put jQuery(document).ready().... instead of $(document).ready(). But if I put the jQuery.fn.greenify = .... replace all the aliases to jQuery - this will also not work outside the jQuery(document).ready()... that's what puzzling me. Could that be a sort of conflict problem in namespacies????

Answer (score 0):

It works but I think you use greenify() before you added the functionality.

Can you show us more code?

```js
(function ( $ ) {

   $.fn.greenify = function() {
      this.css( "color", "green" );
      return this;
  };

  }( jQuery ));
  
jQuery('#test').greenify();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test">
  Black text?
</p>
```

Comment: Yes, I use it the same way  as your  example shows. But to my frustration it just won't work... I'll edit the question for more code...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you try calling jQuery('..').greenify(); before the plugin has been loaded.

You add it if the document is ready - call the plugin  the same way

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.greenify = function() {
        this.css("color", "green");
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
$(function() {
    jQuery('..').greenify();
});
```

Comment: I add the plugin outside (right before, in the same file) the jQuery(document).ready(function(){ ... jQuery("#test").greenify(); ... });